# Loader Image not working properly javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am writing a JavaScript code. I want to display a "loader image". Whenever I click on the button the "loader image" should display for 20 seconds, and then it should redirect to another page. Right now the "image loader" is rendered but won't redirect to the other page.

Here is my current code. Where am I wrong ?

```
jQuery('#double_click_submit').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    jQuery('body').html('<img src="https://xxxxxx/wp-content/uploads/2023/04/Loading_icon.gif">'); // showing loader image
                

    jQuery(this).text("Please wait..Image Generating");
    GrabzIt("NjdiMmRiM2RjZWYyNGViMzkzNDA4MDdjZWRlM2RjMGU=").ConvertPage({"target": "#back-ground", "bheight": -1, "height": -1, "width": -1}).Create();
    setTimeout(function() { 
        var screenshot = jQuery("#screenshot img").attr('src');
        jQuery("#main_select_file").val(screenshot);
        jQuery('#wall_form_add').submit();
    }, 20000);
}
```

Comment: Your example is missing the form markup. The code looks good but there's no way to answer your question without the rest of the code (HTML markup)

Comment: @PawelUchida-Psztyc Actually right now i am working on existing project ( code written by someone) and in this file/current file there is only java script code , there is never html written , hope you understand my point

Comment: If there's no HTML then `jQuery('#double_click_submit').length === 0` and your code does nothing.   *"Whenever I click on the button"* - if there's no HTML... what button?

Comment: `jQuery('body').html(` completely replaces the `body` content - if your javascript is in that body, then it too will be replaced.

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?  (open page in browser, press F12).  eg `GrabzIt function not defined`.   Please provide enough code (including HTML and `<script>` tags for any 3rd party libraries) for us to *reproduce* the issue.  See [mcve].